# caffe.cpp RegisterBrewFunction

Tags: c++, caffe

I was reading the caffe source codes. In the caffe.cpp which is the source of tools/caffe, I encounter the following codes which puzzles me:

```
#define RegisterBrewFunction(func) \
namespace { \
class __Registerer_##func { \
 public: /* NOLINT */ \
  __Registerer_##func() { \
    g_brew_map[#func] = &func; \
  } \
}; \
__Registerer_##func g_registerer_##func; \
}
```

Based on my knowledge, this macro replace RegisterBrewFunction(func) with a anonymous class, and the only thing it has done is add <#func, &func> to g_brew_map.
So why not just doing this like this?

```
#define RegisterBrewFunction(func) g_brew_map[#func]=&func;
```

Hope someone help me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#define` defines a macro that can be used inside a function. When the code reaches this function then the macro argument will be registered. You have to call the function for brewing the coffee.

The original `#define` defines a macro that shall be used at file scope. It creates a more or less anonymous object. The constructor of that object's class will run before `main` is called and registers the function. There is no other function necessary.

Comment: @LiuJingyu "about this", what do you mean? *Macros* is just a way to write text that will be expanded. *Initialization before main()* is a topic found in nearly every C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

Because an assignment may not live at global scope, only inside a function.

This macro can be used in many more places, and indeed will normally live at the top of some source file so that you don't have to call a function to make it work.